# Restrict large VM creation for non-admins in Azure using Azure Policy and RBAC

Tags: azure, role-based-access-control, active-directory

We're trying to restrict normal users(contributors) from creating VMs of large size, they should be able to create VMs of a certain size. I have tried applying the inbuilt azure policy to do that **Allowed virtual machine skus** policy but the policy will be applied to all the users in the subscription. Even owners will not be allowed to create VMs apart from what we allow while applying the policy.

I had gone through a few blogs where they say that we can restrict by user level also, but somehow things not working as expected.

Is there a way to achieve this, please help.